# Awk Program to Determine Maximum

Tags: awk, max, csh

I'm trying to determine the maximum values of columns S2 & S4 but only for the corresponding S1 columns that have BBB.
The output would be S2 max=800 and S4 max=90.
Currently have:
`awk 'BEGIN { FS = " " ; OFS = " "; } { if(NR%3==0){max=$3} { s2+=substr($2,1,3); s4+=substr($4,1,2) } } ; { $3 >= max } END { print "Max S2 = " s2, "; Max S4 = " s4 } ' file.txt`

```
   S1 S2 S3 S4 
   --- --- - --
   AAA 100 A 99
   BBB 200 B 90
   CCC 300 C 80
   AAA 400 A 70
   BBB 500 B 60
   CCC 600 C 50
   AAA 700 A 40
   BBB 800 B 30
   CCC 900 C 20
   AAA 999 A 10
```

Comment: You had added your good efforts in form of code in your initial question. Not sure why you have removed it just now, it's a kind request to please add them back as it's highly encouraged on SO. There is no right or wrong efforts so please put them back in your question.

Comment: Fyi please, I had added them back now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell you are using should not make any difference, it doesn't change the way `awk` behaves. It may change the way you provide variable input to `awk`, but your problem here doesn't require any.

Here you can simply identify the records (lines) containing `BBB` and then keep track of the maximum values for field-2 and field-4 and then output the results using the `END` rule. You can use a traditional `if` or a *ternary* operator as @RavinderSingh13 has used. A traditional `if` would be:

```
awk '/BBB/{
    if ($2 > s2)
        s2 = $2
    if ($4 > s4)
        s4 = $4
}
END{
    printf "S2 max=%d and S4 max=%d\n", s2, s4
}' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in the filename `file`, you can just change to the directory containing `file` (make sure you change `file` to whatever your input file name is) and then select-copy above and middle-mouse-paste into the terminal to test, e.g.

```
$ awk '/BBB/{
>     if ($2 > s2)
>         s2 = $2
>     if ($4 > s4)
>         s4 = $4
> }
> END{
>     printf "S2 max=%d and S4 max=%d\n", s2, s4
> }' file
S2 max=800 and S4 max=90
```

Comment: You are very welcome. If you will be using shell a lot, then take the time to learn `awk`. It is the swiss-army knife of text processing. It is quite easy once you understand `awk` simply reads each record (line) and applies the rules you write in the order you write them. [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) is a great reference. It will pay back ten-fold the time you spend learning it.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following written and tested with shown samples in link https://ideone.com/OMoqG8

```
awk '
$1=="BBB"{
  maxS2=(maxS2>$2?maxS2:$2)
  maxS4=(maxS4>$4?maxS4:$4)
}
END{
  print "max of S2 is:" maxS2 ORS "max of S4 is:" maxS4
}
' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
max of S2 is:800
max of S4 is:90
```

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that I'm trying to implement this within cshell.

Comment: @entropee, your efforts showed you written them in awk. I am not sure about cshell I written this in mobile and tested in mentioned link https://ideone.com/OMoqG8   . You would have mentioned in your question about cshell(even tag is added later point of time fyi). Is it not working ?

Comment: Agreed, thanks so much for your patience and assistance!

Comment: @entropee, your welcome, is it working fine? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: Yes like a charm